# Is it possible to import material from material library in Abaqus CAE using scripts?

Tags: python, plugins, scripting, abaqus, finite-element-analysis

I'm working on Abaqus 6.14 plugin that would help me in my Engineer's Thesis, which I'm writing in Python. According to [Abaqus scripting reference guide](http://abaqus.software.polimi.it/v6.14/books/ker/default.htm) it is possible to import materials from Output Databases (*.odb files) by calling:

```
from abaqus import mdb
mdb.models[name].materialsFromOdb(filename)
```

However, as Abaqus allows user to export/import materials to/from relatively lightweight Material Libraries (*.lib files) and share them between models I would like to import the materials from these rather than from, often bulky, *.odb files.

Of course this can be done manually with ease, although I want to reduce amount of repetitive job with my plugin, as I need to run dozens of simulations on pretty similiar models but with varying materials and some other parameters. I am aware I could also provide necessary materials in template *.cae file too, although this could be quite inconvenient if I had to manually import new material(s) to dozens of models or I had to update existing material's properties.

What am I looking for is a workaround allowing to import materials from material libraries to Abaqus mdb models with Python scripts, but avoiding implementing custom *.lib files parser, if only such workaround exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to know is that Abaqus material library is just a pickled file. No special parser is needed to work with it. You can just use the standard Python libraries [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or [cPickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle). Of course, you need to figure out the exact structure of the objects inside. This is not difficult as you'll see it's a just list of simple tuples.

However, if you have an existing material library and you want to import a material in your Abaqus CAE database, there is an existing method to do it.

There is a method in Abaqus which uses a material string from a material database and creates a material object from that. I can't remember the exact name, but if you import one material manually and look into `abaqus.rpy` file, you will see it inside.

One tricky thing here is that in order to use this method, you need to have a material string from the material library. This can be done by reading the material database file. As already mentioned, this is in pickle format.

As you know, Abaqus already has a way of reading data from the material library and importing it into a CAE model. They have a Python module which you could use, but it can only be used inside a GUI process, not the kernel one. If you want to spend some time, you can figure out which module does that. Inside Abaqus installation folder, you will find some `.pyc` files. If you use a Python decompiler, you can obtain source code for those modules. Look for those beginning with `mat`.

Comment: Thank you, works exactly as expected. To be accurate, the method you mentioned is materials.createMaterialFromDataString(modelname,materialname,version,data). After unpickling library file, you will have list of 5-tuples: the last element in tuple is a dictionary and its property 'data' should be passed as data argument to the function.